# Appending a string to all the python logs aws lambda

Tags: python-3.x, logging, aws-lambda, python-logging

I want to prepend a string to logs generated by all the python modules in my lambda function.

Let's say there are 2 modules

a.py

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
def dummymeth():
   logger.info("hello world")
```

b.py

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
def dummymeth2():
   logger.info("hello world2")
```

...

I want to append a string let's say {tid=123456789987654321 uid=123456765432} before every log. And this string to be appended should be configurable. I tried creating a singleton logging factory but things are not working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a singleton python class and log it from here.

**NOTE: The below code will not work in multithreaded environment.**

```
import logging

class Singleton(type):
    """
    Define an Instance operation that lets clients access its unique
    instance.
    """

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name, bases, attrs)
        cls._instance = None

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance


class SingletonLogger(metaclass=Singleton):
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    extra = None
    context_string = "{}"

    def setContext(self, extra={}):
        self.extra = extra
        self.context_string = self.get_mdc_like_String(extra)

    def info(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.info(self.context_string + " " + msg, *args, **kwargs)

    def error(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.error(self.context_string + " " + msg, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_mdc_like_String(self, parameters):
        message_context_array = []
        for key, value in parameters.items():
            # adding key=value since splunk will recognise it that way.
            message_context_array.append(key + "=" + value)
        return "{" + " ,".join(message_context_array) + "}"
```

Now in your modules you can just do

a.py

```
from src.util.Singleton_logger import SingletonLogger
from b import dummymeth2
logger = SingletonLogger()

logger.setContext({"a":"b", "c":"d"})
def dummymeth():
   logger.info("hello world")
   dummymeth2()
```

b.py

```
from src.util.Singleton_logger import SingletonLogger

logger = SingletonLogger()

def dummymeth2():
   logger.info("hello world")
```